# How solve Intersection types to get proper typescript checks when accessing an object using another object's property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I'm not so sure how to describe this, but I'm trying to make typescript work with the following simplified example:

```js
const a = {
    type: "a",
    original: "a",
} as const

const b = {
    type: "b",
    extra: "b",
} as const

const letters = {
    a,
    b,
} as const

type A = typeof a
type B = typeof b
type Letters = typeof letters

const Comp = {
    a: (a: A) => console.log(a.original),
    b: (b: B) => console.log(b.extra),
}

function log(letter: Letters[keyof Letters]) {
    const Result = Comp[letter.type] // Comp keys match the letters "type"
    Result(letter) // here it fails. Types reduced to 'never'
}
```

I tried forcing some types.

Also I got somehow something working but it only works if I define it as follows:

```js
    if (letter.type === "a") {
        const Result = Comp[letter.type]
        return Result(letter)
    }
    if (letter.type === "b") {
        const Result = Comp[letter.type]
        return Result(letter)
    }
```

unfortunately this is not scalable

Comment: This is the issue described at [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the suggested fix (assuming you don't just want to use a type assertion) is described at [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). You'd need to refactor to use generics and indexing into mapped types. For your code it would look like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wR70vN). Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I have been trying to get a work around this for the last hours. You saved me!
I'll take some time to understand the solution now, I'm not so used to typescript. Thanks again :)

Comment: Okay. I've closed this as a duplicate of some others where the issue is the "correlated union" problem making it look like you need an intersection where you can't make one, and where the fix is refactoring to generic index accesses into mapped types.